# jQuery Masonry fluid images on browser resize

Tags: image, jquery-masonry, fluid-layout

I am trying to build a fluid multi-column layout with images using Masonry. At some browser sizes the multi-column flips into one column. Is there a way to fix this?

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dloAe

```js
$(function(){
  var $container = $('#container');
      
  $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
       $(window).resize(function(){
          $container.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.item',
            isResizable: false,
          });
       }).resize();
    });
});
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

#container {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.item {
    float: left;
    width: 46%;
  padding: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f8/Rho_Ophiuchi.jpg/611px-Rho_Ophiuchi.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cb/Hess_maloyaroslavets.jpg">
  </div>
    <div class="item">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f8/Rho_Ophiuchi.jpg/611px-Rho_Ophiuchi.jpg">
  </div>
    <div class="item">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cb/Hess_maloyaroslavets.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It stayed in two columns for me, right down to the smallest chrome can go.

However, I would suggest setting a min-width (320px) for your container so any smaller than that (which I assume is when it goes to one column) will start the window scrolling instead of pushing it into one column.

What browser are experiencing this on? What size is the window when this problem is occuring? More information in the question = more help in the answers.

Comment: It seems to be a sub-pixel problem. Changing the .item width from 46% to 45.9% solved the issue.